# Find $\tan(x)$ with $BM$ as median

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

I am stuck on this geometry problem.

> ABC is a triangle and BM is one of its medians. Given that $AM=MC$, $\cot(a)=\frac{2}{3}$, $\cot(b)=\frac{8}{5}$, find $\tan x$.

Diagram:
[image: Draw]

My attempts were only met with various nonsensical systems of equations. I would greatly appreciate your help.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Can you write out as many systems of equations as possible, using just those side lengths and angles? Sine rule is a great place to start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Along the median $BM$, consider signed lengths where downwards (e.g. $BM$) is positive, and upwards (e.g. $MB$) is negative.

Drop altitudes $AL$ and $CN$ onto the (extended) median $BM$.

By congruent triangles $\triangle ALM\cong \triangle CNM$, the two altitudes have the same lengths: $AL=CN$, and $M$ is the midpoint of $L$ and $N$:

$$\begin{align*}
LM &= MN\\
&= \frac{LM+MN}{2}\\
&= \frac{LM-BM + BM+MN}{2}\\
&= \frac{BN-BL}{2}\\
&= \frac{|CN|\cot \beta - |AL|\cot \alpha}{2}\\
&= \frac{|AL|(\cot \beta -\cot \alpha)}{2}\\
\end{align*}$$

Consider $x$ as an angle of right-angled $\triangle ALM$,

$$\begin{align*}
\tan x &= \frac{|AL|}{LM}\\
&= \frac{2}{\cot\beta - \cot \alpha}\\
&= \frac{15}{7}
\end{align*}$$

---

### The original trigonometric proof

Along $AC$, consider signed lengths where rightwards (e.g. $AC$) is positive, and leftwards (e.g. $CA$) is negative.

When at $B$, consider signed angles where anti-clockwise (e.g. $\angle ABC$) is positive, and clockwise (e.g. $\angle CBA$) is negative.

Drop altitude $BE$ onto $AC$, and let $h$ be the height $BE$.

Then using the identity of tangent of sum,

$$\begin{align*}
\cot \alpha &= \cot\left(\angle ABE + \angle EBM\right)\\
&= \frac{1-\tan\angle ABE \cdot \tan \angle EBM}{\tan\angle ABE + \tan\angle EBM}\\
&= \frac{1-AE \cdot EM/h^2}{AE/h + EM/h}\\
&= \frac{1-(AM-EM) \cdot EM/h^2}{AM/h}\\
\cot \beta &= \cot(\angle EBC - \angle EBM)\\
&= \frac{1+\tan \angle EBC \cdot \tan EBM}{\tan \angle EBC - \tan \angle EBM}\\
&= \frac{1+EC \cdot EM/h^2}{EC/h - EM/h}\\
&= \frac{1+(EM+MC) \cdot EM/h^2}{MC/ h}\\
\end{align*}$$

Using $AM = MC$,

$$\begin{align*}
\cot \beta - \cot \alpha
&= \frac{1+(EM+MC) \cdot EM/h^2}{MC/h} - \frac{1-(AM-EM) \cdot EM/h^2}{AM/h}\\
&= \frac{(EM+AM) \cdot EM/h^2 + (AM-EM)\cdot EM/h^2}{AM/ h}\\
&= \frac{2AM\cdot EM/h^2}{AM/h}\\
&= 2EM/h\\
&= \frac{2}{\tan x}\\
\tan x &= \frac{2}{\cot \beta - \cot \alpha} = \frac{15}{7}
\end{align*}$$